# Join on multiple columns and in one of the integer columns join by choosing minimum difference

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I got table t1 and i want to join it with table t2 below on columns a, b and c

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|a        |b        |c        |
+---------+---------+---------+
|473200   |1        |1.-1-1   |
|472400   |10       |1.-1-1   |
|472800   |10       |1.-1-1   |
|473200   |93       |1.-1-1   |
|472800   |26240    |1.-1-1   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

t2

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|a        |b        |c        |
+---------+---------+---------+
|473200   |1        |1.-1-1   |
|472400   |10       |1.-1-1   |
|472800   |10       |1.-1-1   |
|473200   |93       |1.-1-1   |
|472800   |26250    |1.-1-1   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

When I join only on a and c the result is

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|t1.b     |t2.b     |a        |c        |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|93       |1        |473200   |1.-1-1   |
|1        |1        |473200   |1.-1-1   |
|10       |10       |472400   |1.-1-1   |
|10       |10       |472800   |1.-1-1   |
|26240    |10       |472800   |1.-1-1   |
|93       |93       |473200   |1.-1-1   |
|1        |93       |473200   |1.-1-1   |
|10       |26250    |472800   |1.-1-1   |
|26240    |26250    |472800   |1.-1-1   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I try to achieve is to add column b to 'on' clause so that join happens on minimum difference in b column.

Desired result

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|t1.b     |t2.b     |a        |c        |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|1        |1        |473200   |1.-1-1   |
|10       |10       |472400   |1.-1-1   |
|10       |10       |472800   |1.-1-1   |
|93       |93       |473200   |1.-1-1   |
|26240    |26250    |472800   |1.-1-1   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I saw something similar here

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73804/how-to-retrieve-closest-value-based-on-look-up-table

but not sure how to apply to my case.

Comment: In your example, you have two rows for 472800 in each table.  What should happen if there were an unequal number?

Comment: @jjanes i just need to join using closest value from b....if unequal number we take the one closest from b and filter out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and calculate the differences for column `c`, then use `distinct on` to return only one row per `(a, c)` ordered by the difference.

```
with joined as (
  select t1.a, t1.c, t1.b as b1, t2.b as b2, t2.b - t1.b as b_diff
    from t1
         join t2 
           on t2.a = t1.a
          and t2.b = t1.b
          and t1.b <= t2.b
)
select distinct on (a, c) b1, b2, a, c
  from joined
 order by a, c, b_diff
;
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is a lateral join:

```
select t1.*, t2.b b2
from t1
cross join lateral (
    select t2.*
    from t2
    where t2.a = t1.a and t2.c = t1.c
    order by abs(t2.b - t1.b)
    limit 1
)
```

Another possibility is `distinct on` - but you need a primary key for `t1`. Assuming that `(a, c)` tuple uniquely identify each row in `t1`, you would go:

```
select distinct on (t1.a, t1.c) t1.*, t2.b b2
from t1
inner join t2 on t2.a = t1.a and t2.c = t1.c
order by t1.a, t1.c, abs(t2.b - t1.b)
```